# How to get specific items with Nokogiri from poorly structured HTML

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri

I'm scraping "[The Broadway Bookshop](http://broadwaybookshophackney.com/events/?event=archive)" for an events list using Nokogiri, but the page is more or less all one block of content. I can't seem to access the specific `h3` items with `class="news"` using:

```rb
def scrape_broadway_books
  base_url = "https://broadwaybookshophackney.com"
  slug = "/events/?event=archive"
  url = base_url + slug
  unparsed_page = HTTParty.get(url)
  parsed_page = Nokogiri::HTML(unparsed_page)
  events_list = parsed_page.at_css("div#content")
  # binding.pry
  events = Array.new
  events_list.each do |item|
    puts item.css("h3.news").text
  end
end
```

This gives me the error:

```
undefined method `css' for ["id", "content"]:Array (NoMethodError)
```

If I try to iterate over the `events_list` I still only end up with one event written to my data file:

```rb
events_list = parsed_page.css("div#content")
events = Array.new
events_list.each_with_index do |event, index|
  event = {
    index: index,
    title: event.css("h3.news").text
  }
  events << event
end
File.open("./_data/events.json", "w") do |file|
  file.write(JSON.pretty_generate(events))
end
```

Why can't I iterate over the content div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`at_css` [returns a single element](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/nokogiri/Nokogiri%2FXML%2FSearchable:at_css). It won't be iterable; when you try to iterate it, you're getting the attributes of the div. Use `parsed_page.css("div#content")` instead if you want to get a list of elements to iterate.

Or, more succinctly:

```
events = parsed_page.css("div#content h3.news").map(&:text)
```

With that bit of refactoring done, you might also consider refactoring the method a bit so that your URL fetch and document parse are reusable, which cleans up your `scrape_broadway_books` to a single responsibility:

```
def scrape_broadway_books
  doc = doc_from_url("https://broadwaybookshophackney.com",
    "/events/?event=archive")
  doc.css("div#content h3.news").map(&:text)
end

def doc_from_url(*parts)
  uri = URI.join(*parts)
  Nokogiri::HTML(HTTParty.get(uri))
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but it seems `div#content` only contains 1 item. I will add some extra code to the OP to explain.

Comment: div#content only finds one div. Within that div, there are multiple `h3.news`. `event.css("h3.news").text` gets just the text for the first matched `h3.news`. Just search for and iterate `.css("div#content h3.news")` and build an event out of each item - no need to perform another `.css` search within your loop.

Comment: sorry if these questions are obvious... so, using your example `events = parsed_page.css("h3.news, p.pub").map(&:text)` gives me an array of titles and dates, but each event title and its date are not grouped together in the array. is this a question of writing the right `#map` block? thank you.

Comment: That's going to be more tricky, because the date is in a `p.pub strong` tag that is a *sibling* to the H3. You'll have to iterate the list of h3 elements, then get the next sibling from each of them, and then pull the date out of that.